# I am trying to create a Marketplace Smart contract to buy and sell NFT with ERC20 token but getting error when I try to implement buy function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, nft, erc725

```
I am trying to create a Marketplace Smart contract to buy and sell NFT with ERC20 token.
```

My Token.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract YourToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Solu", "SOLU") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000 * 10 ** 18);
    }
}
```

MY NFT.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";


contract NFTToken is ERC721 {
    
    string public nameNFT;
    string public nameSymbol;
    string public nftTokenURI;
    uint256 public nftId;

    //Keep the record of  nfts
    mapping(uint256 => string) public tokenURIExists;
    
    
    //Keep the record for nfts value => give id returns cost 
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public tokenIdToValue;
    

    
    // Base URI
    string  _baseURIextended;
    
    constructor () ERC721("Samresh", "SAM") {
        nameNFT = "Sam";
        nameSymbol = "SAM";
    
    }
    
    
    
    function setBaseURI(string memory baseURI_) external  {
        _baseURIextended = baseURI_;
    }
    
    
    
    function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) internal virtual {
        require( _exists(tokenId),"ERC721Metadata: URI set of nonexistent token");
        tokenURIExists[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
    }
    
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _baseURIextended;
    }
    
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
            require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

            string memory _tokenURI = tokenURIExists[tokenId];
            string memory base = _baseURI();
            
            // If there is no base URI, return the token URI.
            if (bytes(base).length == 0) {
                return _tokenURI;
            }
            // If both are set, concatenate the baseURI and tokenURI (via abi.encodePacked).
            if (bytes(_tokenURI).length > 0) {
                return string(abi.encodePacked(base, _tokenURI));
            }
            // // If there is a baseURI but no tokenURI, concatenate the tokenID to the baseURI.
            // return string(abi.encodePacked(base, tokenId.toString()));
            return string(abi.encodePacked(base, tokenId));
    }
        
  
    function Mint (string memory _tokenURI, uint256 _nftPrice) public returns (uint256)  {
        require(msg.sender != address(0));
        nftTokenURI = _tokenURI;
        // used as token id 
        nftId ++;
        // check if a token exists with the above token id => incremented counter
        require(!_exists(nftId));
        tokenIdToValue[nftId] = _nftPrice;
        _mint(msg.sender,nftId);
        _setTokenURI(nftId, nftTokenURI);
        
        return nftId;
        
    }
    
    function tokenPrice (uint256 _tokenID) public view returns (uint256 nftPrice) {
        require(!_exists(nftId));
        nftPrice = tokenIdToValue[_tokenID]; 
    } 
    
    
}
```

MY MarketPlace.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

import "./3_Ballot.sol";
import "./1_Storage.sol";


contract NFTMarketPlace {
    
    YourToken token;
    NFTToken  NFT;
   
    
   
  
    //keep the record for tokenID is listed on sale or not
    mapping(uint256 => bool) public tokenIdForSale;
    
    
    
    //keep the address of the nft buyer
    mapping(uint256 => address) public nftBuyers;
    
    
    constructor (address tokenAddress, address NFTAddress)  {
        token = YourToken(tokenAddress);
        NFT = NFTToken(NFTAddress);
       
    
    }
    
    function nftSale(uint256 _tokenId,bool forSale) external {
        require(msg.sender == NFT.ownerOf(_tokenId),"Only owners can change this status");
        tokenIdForSale[_tokenId] = forSale;
    }
    
   
    function nftBuy(uint256 _tokenId) payable public {
        require(tokenIdForSale[_tokenId],"Token must be on sale first");
        uint nftPrice = NFT.tokenPrice(_tokenId);
        require(msg.value >= nftPrice, "Insufficient balance.");
        
        token.transfer(payable(NFT.ownerOf(_tokenId)),nftPrice);
        nftBuyers[_tokenId] = msg.sender;
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Everything is working as expected but when I am trying to buy a token I am getting an error
**Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.**

I am deploying code on remix IDE and sending 1000 Wei as msg.value

I am a newbie in solidity and any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error you've got is not related to the code. Your buy function is a `payable` function. So you've to send some ***ETH*** in the ***msg.value***

In remix for doing it, you'll see a parameter called ***value*** on the left side of the window. Input the amount of ether you wish to transfer in there. The function should work as expected! viola!

[image]

Comment: I am sending msg.value that I forgot to mention

Comment: are you sending more than your balance?

Comment: I am sending 1000 wei

Comment: are you using ETH as payment for your NFT (or) your token ?

Comment: I am using tokens.

Comment: You should use approve() and transferFrom() methods to process payments from user wallet if you're processing token payments.

Refer the gist here https://gist.github.com/sujithsomraaj/51cca2232f6972a0daf7bcf7bbc36465 for code example.

Also first approve your tokens to be spent by the marketplace contract before calling buy option